# Symfony Form Events

Tags: symfony

So I was going through the symfony official documentation for form events https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html.

But I am not able to grab the concept apart from the simple definitions of the events. What I got from this is `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` is triggered before `setData()` is called and `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA`  is triggered after `setData()` is called. And `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`, `FormEvents::SUBMIT` & `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` are triggered before, during and after Form::submit() is called. I am also confused about the usage of Model, Norm and View data.

Can someone demonstrate all five events with a working example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the events to conditionally modify the form. I will not give you demonstrations of all events but here is one. I use the event to fill an Entity type with specific entities. (The ProfileCategory type extends the EntityType).

```
$builder->addEventListener(
       FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
       function (FormEvent $event) use ($user) {
           $form = $event->getForm();

           $formOptions = array(
               'class'         => ProfileCategory::class,
               'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                   // build a custom query
                   $user_id = $user->getId();
                   $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('pc');
                   $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('pc.user', $user_id));
                   return $qb;
               },
               'label' => 'Categorie',
               'expanded' => false,
               'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'profile-list'
                ],
           );

           $form->add('profileCategory', EntityType::class, $formOptions);
       }
);
```